# mingw32-make install "multiple target patterns" error when installing opencv

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, mingw, mingw32

I've been trying to build OpenCV-4.5.1 from source with CMake 3.20.0-rc3. I could run `mingw32-make` after configuring and generating the files from `cmake`, but this error always pops up when I try to run `mingw32-make install`.

[image]

```
D:\build1>mingw32-make install
3rdparty/openjpeg/openjp2/CMakeFiles/libopenjp2.dir/compiler_depend.make:4: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3433: 3rdparty/openjpeg/openjp2/CMakeFiles/libopenjp2.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:165: all] Error 2
```

I tried looking through the makefiles shown in the cmd but its really long and I have really no idea what to look into. From the google searches I've done it seems like it's to do with syntax error in the makefiles. Can you guys help me out with this?

Edit: first 5 lines of 3rdparty/openjpeg/openjp2/CMakeFiles/libopenjp2.dir/compiler_depend.make

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MinGW Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.20

3rdparty/openjpeg/openjp2/CMakeFiles/libopenjp2.dir/bio.c.obj: C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/opencv-4.5.1/3rdparty/openjpeg/openjp2/bio.c \
  C\\:\\Users\\XXXX\\Downloads\\opencv-4.5.1\\3rdparty\\openjpeg\\openjp2\\bio.c \
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.  They can't be copy/pasted and they can't be searched.  Please use copy/paste of the text, and use formatting features to make sure they're legible.

Comment: Without looking at anything, these packages are most likely intended to be compiled on a UNIX system (Linux or MacOS), not on a Windows system.  The error you're seeing is a very common issue trying to use makefiles with Windows-style paths (UNIX paths don't contain drive letters like `C:` etc.)  You should look through the instructions of the package for special instructions compiling on Windows.  Most likely you'll need to use cygwin or some other UNIX-based environment, not cmd.com.

Comment: edited the post to include the error message

Comment: Does it make sense if I give this a try with msys?

Comment: "I tried looking through the makefiles shown in the cmd ..." - Please, add to your post the exact line 4 from the file `3rdparty/openjpeg/openjp2/CMakeFiles/libopenjp2.dir/compiler_depend.make` (the error message refers exactly to that line).

Comment: added the first 5 lines of the compier_depend.make file

Comment: Please, show the **exact** content, without XXX. It seems that exactly this part is responsible for the problem.

Comment: ohh thats my username, for privacy purposes i added 4 X's there